# Lexical and Module Scoping in Rascal

Tags: rascal

How do I implement the lexical and module scoping in the rascal language workbench?

I need to implement lexical and module scoping within a DSL, please materials/code repository on how that is done in Rascal would also be appreciated.

Comment: Are you interested in a static semantics (like a type checker) or a dynamic semantics (handling scope at runtime)?

Comment: I am interested in static semantics

Answer (score 0):

We use the [TypePal framework](https://github.com/usethesource/typepal) most of the time. It is a declarative and fast name resolution, type checker, and type inferencing framework.

The project contains a number of instructive examples:

- module scopes and imports: https://github.com/usethesource/typepal/blob/master/src/examples/modfun/Syntax.rsc
- classical programming language (including lexical scoping rules) https://github.com/usethesource/typepal/tree/master/src/examples/pascal
- and some more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, How do I wire this TypePal Framework with my language project so I could use it with my project?

Comment: It's best to use `util::Reflective` `newRascalProject` to set up a project with a pom.xml. Then add typepal to the pom as a dependency, restart your terminal or your IDE and you can use the typepal modules as if they are in your own project. O, yes in RASCAL.MF you have to add `|lib://typepal|` to `Require-Dependencies` as well.

Comment: I was able get TypePal 0.4.10 into the search path now it visible on the rascal console but fails to resolve the TypePal module name when I use it in a rascal file.

Comment: ok. that can happen sometimes. please restart VScode? that could refresh the search path for the editor.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Eclipse and I have restarted the IDE a couple of times but it still fails to resolve the module. I would have assume if the module appears in the search path, it should be available for use anywhere within the project but that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: Mmm. yes. In Eclipse you may need some additional configuration to make it work. I'll ask around.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will be waiting for a feedback!

Comment: Good day sir, I just came to check back on the Eclipse configuration for TypePal any progress yet? And also how do I set up Rascal on VSCode maybe I could try the VSCode option too, because that also doesn't seem to work straightforward? @jurgen

Comment: HI @PiusArhanbhunde; the eclipse release is a bit behind the VScode release now and depending on typepal does not seem to work very well. The way it does work is to use an old typepal version from the rascal libraries updates site: https://update.rascal-mpl.org/rascal-eclipse-libraries-update-site-snapshot you can turn your own project into a plugin project and depend on the typepal plugin using META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: In the meantime I'll try and work on a new Eclipse release for the most modern typepal dependency via pom.xml

Comment: Hi @jurgen; I have tried out what you suggested using TypePal 0.4.10 with Eclipse 2022-03 and Rascal 0.26.5, it seems to see TypePal in the Rascal Console but there is still squiggle red lines in Eclipse when I reference TypePal e.g analysis::typepal::TypePal; is highlighted as an error. My question is, is there are a particular combination Eclipse, Rascal and TypePal version that works, so I could try that out?

Comment: Hi Pius; we are working on that but in the meantime I think you could turn off the typechecker in the eclipse preference pane for rascal and get your work done.

Comment: Hi @jurgen; how exactly do I turn off the typechecker in eclipse?

Comment: In the Eclipse Preferences view (CMD+, on Mac) there is a Rascal tab with the option to enable or disable the 'compiler'

Comment: Good day @jurgen; it still didn't work, anyway I had to paste the directory TypePal analysis directory from the git repository within my project directory, it seems to work fine, would be using this as a temporary solution until the eclipse fix is complete.